# Context shows empty views block

Tags: views, 7

I've got a views block that shows data from node field.

I've set up a contextual filter

NID:

WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE

Provide default value: content ID from url.

I've also set up a context show this block

Condition: Node Type

Reaction Block

It works fine, but if the field is empty it will show Block title and empty content.

Is there a way I can hide the block if the view is empty?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added FILTER CRITERIA: my_field (NOT NULL)... it was so simple...

Comment: The same happens when using **Display Suite** when displaying an empty *block field* (with a view in it). Adding the filter criterium `my_field:fid` and setting it to *is not empty (NOT NULL)* takes care of this indeed. Thanks!